# XCode 5 build Rule vs Build Phase

Tags: xcode, build-automation

I know in xCode 3 build rules happened first but in xCode 4 they happened last. Is this still the case or did they revert it back? I have a script that creates/updates a handful of header files and that needs to happen prior to the general compile. Should I do this as a phase or a rule?